# Sending data from a PHP script to a C# applicaiton

Tags: c#, php, serialization, interop

When C# app is ran, it POSTS a request to the PHP server, which wants to return an array.  What's an easy way to load this array's contents into C# for using with there.

For clarification, this array is a PHP stdClass object that contains strings, floats, and other stdClass objects.  I want to get a similar data structure on the C# end with the same data.

Also, I know stdClass != arrays, but they're pretty simular so that they can be encoded the same way witn most encoding mechanisms.

Comment: Define `returns an array`. A web server usually returns string contents. How is this array encoded? Are you using some specific protocol?

Comment: @Darin - I have a stdClass object as described in the ammended question.  The question is how do I encode this array so that C# can decode it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know C# but [JSON](http://www.json.org/) encoding using [json_encode()](http://www.php.net/json_encode) is pretty popular in the web app world as a simple means to transfer simple structures across platforms.

There is a variety of parser classes on the C# end, scroll down in the first link.

Comment: May I suggest looking at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb299886.aspx#intro_to_json_topic5

Comment: Thanks.  I ended up going with LINQ to JSON ( http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx ) for it.