# How to upload applications written in C# onto a website using Drupal?

Tags: c#, drupal-7

Please answer for Dummies ;) ... Absolute newbie to web programming, especially new to Drupal. We have some modules written in C#, that access a database in MySQL and works on it (it's a student information system actually. We have some forms created in C#, through which interface student's can enter their details onto the database and we have desktop applications which work on those data). Now we need to create a website so that student's can enter information through the internet. We can not re-write the whole modules in PHP, and we want to use Drupal to create the website. So how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really a direct answer, but some points that you need to consider. How complicated this will be depends on how much interoperability you need between the C# code and Drupal.

Does Drupal need to use the forms written in C# in order to enter the data in the DB, or could data entry be done directly from PHP (As in, is there any validation or processing of data in the C# forms that needs to be done?)  If not, it seems like the easiest way would be to build a page in Drupal that can enter the data directly into the MySQL database.

Otherwise, the easiest way to get the programmes to talk to each other might be outputting the data to another format — e.g. XML or JSON. ([Here's a similar question with someone using JSON as the intermediary data type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2709349/sending-data-from-a-php-script-to-a-c-sharp-applicaiton)) You could have your PHP form create an XML document in a temp folder, with the C# programme polling this folder for new files every X minutes and use them as an input into its application.

It will really depend on your workflow — how immediate does the processing of data need to be? Is the flow of data in/out, or in only — i.e does there need to be a set of results returned to the user?